# ngOnInit ignores CSS transition

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-components

I have div which I would like to have its width increase from 0 - 100 in a 3s interval using CSS transition property. When I change this property in Chrome Developer tools, it grows nicely from 0-100 along the duration of the 3 seconds. However, if I apply the style from the component's `ngOnInit()`, it's instant. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I did solve the problem by myself, however an answer which also explains why it works would be great.

Component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'notFound',
    templateUrl: 'app/notFound.component/notFound.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class NotFoundComponent {
    ngOnInit() {
        (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.determinate')).style.width = "100%";
    }
}
```

Component.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <i class="material-icons error">error_outline</i>
    <div class="not-found-text"> No such page 'round here.</div>
    <a [routerLink]="['Menu']" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue">
        <i class="material-icons">home</i>
        <!--home-->
    </a>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="determinate"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .progress {
        margin-top: 30px;
        background: white;
    }

    .determinate {
        width: 0%;
        background: #2196F3;
        transition: width 3s ease-in-out;
    }        
</style>
```

Comment: I think you should take a look at the Angular 2 Docs about Lifecycle Hooks. OnInit fires once right after OnChanges. You may need to implement another hook. Also, you might need to implement it properly for TypeScript tooling with export class whatever implements hook {} -- chain them by: hook1, hook2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by wrapping the call in a 0ms `setTimeout`. What a suprise.

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.determinate')).style.width = "100%";
    }, 0);
}
```